# React native project on android crashes as soon as you open the apk file

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

So I've been working on a React Native project, I'm on a Mac and when I run my apk file generated by the command `./gradlew assembleRelease` and install it on my Google Pixel 4a I try to open the app and it instantly crashes and closes. However, when I run it in the emulator via command `react-native run-android` it works as expected. During the build, installation and even opening the app on my actual device it never gives a single error. Nothing has changed to my knowledge since the last time I ran the build command and it was working before so I'm lost and confused as to why this is happening. This also my first react-native project so maybe being a noob I'm missing something very obvious. Also iOS has absolutely no issues, any feedback or tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

My `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        googlePlayServicesLocationVersion = "17.0.0"  // Or higher.
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        appCompatVersion = "1.1.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven {
        // react-native-background-fetch
        url("${project(':react-native-background-fetch').projectDir}/libs")
        }
        maven {
          // Required for react-native-background-geolocation
          url("${project(':react-native-background-geolocation').projectDir}/libs")
        }
        maven {
          // Required for zoho chat widget
          url("https://maven.zohodl.com/")
        }
        maven {
            // Required for react-native-background-fetch
            url("${project(':react-native-background-fetch').projectDir}/libs")
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = "mapbox"
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
            }
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "NAME",
  "version": "1.2.8",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation": "^1.0.5",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.5",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.8",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "11.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "11.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.0-next.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.0.0-next.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.0-next.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.0-next.6",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "expo-web-browser": "^9.0.0",
    "firebase": "^7.24.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.16.2",
    "mobx": "^6.1.8",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^3.2.0",
    "mobx-state-tree": "^5.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mst-persist": "^0.1.3",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-background-fetch": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-background-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.0.8",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-portalize": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.18.1",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.3.1",
    "react-native-zohosalesiq-mobilisten": "^2.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.63.51",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "mobx-flipper": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-flipper": "^0.81.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "arrowParens": "always",
    "printWidth": 100,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "all"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think last version of RN  doesn't open app if Andorid's version is 4. Default it must be 5 . Please try it Android 5 if it is possible

Comment: You can use Logcat on android to see what happend! 
You must run `./gradlew assembleRelease` and `./gradlew installRelease` for your emulator and when you open the app if it crashes, in Logcat you see what happened and what is the error. For better result you can type your app package name in search box and set which kind of log to Error in drop down to only show Error related to your application.

Comment: @Roa Are you talking about on my android device?

Comment: I used logcat but I don’t think any of the errors were related to the app crash

Comment: can you share another `build.gradle` from `/app` and `package.json` ?

Comment: @Edofx The build is already above and I just added the package.json

Comment: @TomBird no, thats not `build.gradle` from `/app` . there's two `build.gradle` in projects react-native . please copy from `{project}/android/app/build.gradle` not from `{project}/android/build.gradle`

Comment: I ended up figuring out what happened, basically there was a chat app that was initialized in the App.tsx that caused a memory leak and needed to be moved into the component definition itself.